# Adding images to a sheet is hitting an arbitrary limit

Tags: vba, excel, image

I've been adding images to an excel sheet based on each queried result. I tried a query that returned 1000 results (each in a new row) however only 405 of the associated pictures showed up. Is there a max number of pictures on a sheet or am I doing something wrong?

```
Sub insertLocalPicture(localPicFileDir As String, PictureFileName As String)
Dim pic As Shape
Dim xTop As Integer
xTop = ActiveCell.Top + 1
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(localPicFileDir + PictureFileName + ".jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)

With pic
    .Top = xTop
    .Left = 0
    .Width = 107
    .Height = 80
End With
Set pic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code and seeing what happens on the 406th instance of trying to add the picture? Also, and not sure if this relevant, but some (or a lot) of the pictures may be laying on top of each other, depending on where your ActiveCell is each time.

Comment: im stepping through the code right now but its not overlaying on top of another picture because I looked up 'Picture 406' in the upper left hand box and it came up as an invalid name, whereas 'Picture '405' point at the picture. I just added a boolean on the function and made it return false always; the calling code is...   
If insertLocalPicture(targetFolder + folderDestWColon + ":", LTrim(RTrim(LCase(ActiveCell.value)))) = True Then
ix = ix + 1
End If
MsgBox ix  
The MsgBox prints 595!!! WTF

Comment: You might want to use "&" instead of "+" for concatenating? Also check if the `localPicFileDir & PictureFileName & ".jpg"` exists

Comment: Put a counter on the code and set a watch so the code breaks right when picture 405 is added. Then step through it to see why Pic 406 and beyond are not added. Siddharth's comments may prove to be your bug, or you may find it is something else.

Comment: So the code is breaking at xTop = ActiveCell.Top + 1 when ActiveCell.Top is around 32768. I changed to xTop = (NumOfPics * 80) + 1 but the variable just wont hold it so im changing it to a Long from an Integer... let see?

Comment: Simple change of original code 'Dim xTop As Long' fixed the problem! Dohhhh, don't you have a love/hate relationship with such simple fixes?!

Comment: Great stuff. I ran into this problem a few months back. Just goes to show how good the mind is when I couldn't see the connection to this! Integer only holds numbers between -32,768 and 32,768 (or around there). You can search on web to figure it out. Long is the trick!

Comment: When you have enough points, its best to post your own answer as an answer and accept it. This way others can find the answer more quickly.

Comment: I always declare integer-type numbers `As Long` unless I know specifically that I am going to assign an Integer value to the variable. Ex: an API function that returns an Integer. Even then I should probably use `As Long` anyway.

Comment: And I agree with [Siddharth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102887/excel-macro-sheet-max-picture-limit#comment14542306_11102887) that the concatenation character for VBA is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 1):

As per user1466660,

The error, which occured at ***cell* 32,768** was fixed by recasting

```
Dim xTop As Integer
```

as

```
Dim xTop As Long
```

As Scott Holtzman noted, integer variables can only hold values from -32,768 and 32,768. For this reason, Jimmy Pena recommends that variables be cast `As Long` unless the marco designer knows they should be used differently.

Comment: I wanted this answer posted, as it is useful, but user1466660 has not been on for a month, and I did not want credit for an answer already post here but just not formatted into the right "box".